# Accessing QAbstractListModel item in Qml without using a ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have subclassed QAbstractListModel in order to have a model on the qml side. I can easily use this model in ListViews and other similar components that deal with models, however, I can't access it directly. This is what I am trying without success:

```
myModel[0].name // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Is this possible? Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: Show your code please. At least `myModel` initialization in QML

Answer (score 2):

(1) You're mixing up roles and properties.

Your model implements roles which are used to feed a delegate in a view. In your code, you try to access a property.

(2) A model is not an array, where you can access rows by the `[]` operator.

But you can write a getter function to achieve exactly that:

```
class ConversationListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum ConversationRoles {
        IdRole = Qt::UserRole, // 256
        NameRole,
    };
    explicit ConversationListModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    Q_INVOKABLE ConversationModel* get(quint32 conversationId) const;

signals:
    // ...
```

Than you need a data type that represents a row, e.g. `ConversationModel`. Now you can access a row using

```
myModel.get(0).name
```

As stated in (1), you now need to give `ConversationModel` a property called `name`

```
public:
    explicit ConversationModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name NOTIFY nameChanged)
    QString name() const;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access generic model (based on `QAbstractListModel`) easily when you use DelegateModel model as a mediator.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQml.Models 2.2

DelegateModel {
  id: delegateModel
}
MyModel {
  id: myModel
  onDataLoaded: {
    delegateModel.model = myModel;
    for (var row = 0; row < myModel.rowCount(); row++) {
      var item = delegateModel.items.get(row).model;
      console.log("  name " + row + ":" + item.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the (correct) solution of Simon Warta work, you have to register ConversationModel as QML type. For example in your main you have to state

```
qmlRegisterType<ConversationModel>("ConversationModel", 1, 0, "ConversationModel");
```

Then in your qml file you have to import this type with

```
import ConversationModel 1.0
```

Afterwards everything works as expected and you can use

```
myModel.get(0).name
```

in your qml code, given that myModel is of type ConversationListModel and was registered using [QDeclarativeContext::setContextProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8///qdeclarativecontext.html#setContextProperty).