# How can I access QSortFilterProxyModel elements in QML outside of a ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which is accessible from my QML code. I am using it in a `ListView` in my QML code, but I also would like to access the first element of it outside of my `ListView`.

Let's say I call my `QSortFilterProxyModel` `sortedObjects`. In the `ListView` I just pass it to the `model` property, like `model: sortedObjects` and then in the `delegate` property I can access it's roles, by the specified role names. How can I do this outside of a `ListView`? Something like `sortedObjects[0].someRoleName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mcchu pointed out in his post, there is a function called `index` and `data` in `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Unfortunately if I try to call these functions on my `QSortFilterProxyModel` in QML, then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Property 'index' of object QSortFilterProxyModel(0x7fcff0c2af90) is not a function
```

Therefore as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138035/accessing-qabstractlistmodel-item-in-qml-without-using-a-listview) post suggested. I have created a separate C++ class, which receives a const pointer of my `QSortFilterProxyModel` and creates a function, which then wraps the `index` and `data` functions and returns the desired value. This class is registered so it can be called from QML code.

Here is the code:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SomeClass(const QSortFilterProxyModel* sortedModel) {
        m_sortedModel = sortedModel;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getValue() {
        QVariant someTypeRole = m_sortedModel->data(m_sortedModel->index(0, 0), SomeModelClass::SomeRoles::SomeTypeRole);
        if (someTypeRole.isValid()) {
            return type = someTypeRole.toString(); // I know it is a QString for sure, but there are mechanisms to find out the type of the role
        }

        return QVariant();
    }

private:
    const QSortFilterProxyModel* m_sortedModel;
};
```

EDIT:

As @Mitch pointed out in his comment @mcchu's solution works, but only from Qt 5.5.

Answer (score 4):

`QSortFilterProxyModel` is a `QAbstractItemModel`. And in `QAbstractItemModel`, you can access the element in the model by calling two `Q_INVOKABLE` functions in QML:

1. [`index`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) to get a `QModelIndex`, and then
2. [`data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) to get the value of a role in that index

For example, assume that the hash value of `someRoleName` is 1234 (defined in the [`roleNames`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) in your model). You can get the value of `someRoleName` in row 0 (and column 0 if the model is a list) like the following function in QML:

```
function printSomeRoleNameInRow0()
{
    var row = 0, col = 0, someRoleName = 1234;
    var idx = sortedObjects.index(row, col);
    var value = sortedObjects.data(idx, someRoleName);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was thinking with the same logic what you explained above, but I get `TypeError: Property 'index' of object QSortFilterProxyModel(0x7fcff0c2af90) is not a function`. I end it up creating a C++ class which receives a const pointer of my `QSortFilterProxyModel` and does the same thing basically. Then I register it so I can call it from QML. I'll post my solution in a couple minutes.

Comment: @Silex, the functions were only made invokable in Qt 5.5, though no one could expect you to know that, because there was unfortunately no change log entry nor documentation to reflect it.

Comment: That is a really useful information @Mitch, Thanks!

Comment: The problem with using invokables like this is that bindings using them won't react on changes in the model